# Zip not working well with custom iterator function in Scala

Tags: scala

I am experimenting with zippers in Scala and I am having difficulties getting custom iterator functions to work with them.

I have the following sample code:

```
Iterator
  .continually("s")
  .zip((1 to 5).iterator)
  .takeWhile {
    case ("s", 2) => println("two"); true
    case ("s", i) => println(i); true
  }
  .foreach { f: (String, Int) =>
    println(f)
  }
```

When I run it, it prints out the results I am expecting:

```
1
(s,1)
two
(s,2)
3
(s,3)
4
(s,4)
5
(s,5)
```

However, when I swap the `takeWhile` with my custom `takeDoWhile` (it includes the last failing result), I get something that is not expected:

```
1
(s,1)
1
(s,1)
1
(s,1)
1
(s,1)
1
(s,1)
1
(s,1)
...
(goes on forever)
```

Here is the code for the `takeDoWhile`:

```
implicit final class InclusiveIterator[A](it: => Iterator[A]){
  @inline def takeDoWhile(predicate: A => Boolean): Iterator[A] = new AbstractIterator[A] {
    private var continue: Boolean = true

    def hasNext: Boolean = it.hasNext && continue

    def next(): A = {
      if(continue){
        val result: A = it.next()
        if (!predicate(result)) continue = false
        result // Give the result even if the predicate fails, but only once.
      }else{
        empty.next()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The weird thing is my `takeDoWhile` works perfectly fine as long as there is no zipper involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused you are using [by name parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/default-parameter-values.html): `it: => Iterator[A]` for `InclusiveIterator`, and since **by name parameter** will eval in every time it used.

Since `it` in `takeDoWhile` method it will reeval in any place it used, so `it.next` will not change the **it** iterator's offset.

there is an example to explain **by name parameter** for eval:

```
  def foo(name: => String): Unit = {
    println(name)
    println(name)
    println(name)
  }
  foo({println("start"); "end"})
  >start
  >end
  >start
  >end
  >start
  >end
```

In the above example, the `name` by name parameter will eval 3 times in `println(name)`.

So for your usage, you should not use the **by name parameter**, use **by value parameter** directly.